# Difference between Original-title and title

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am generating a image dynamically through Jquery.

Markup :

```
  var tr=  '<img class="savedNote" id="imgSavedNote_' + checkListItems[i].Name + '" src="images/notepad2.png" title="Click To Open" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="top" style="display:none;cursor:pointer"/>'
```

So currently the title is "Click To Open" and it comes properly on the image .

Now I am setting the title of the image on a button click which I am doing like below and happening perfectly :

```
$('#imgSavedNote_' + checkListValues[i].Text).prop('title', 'Nitin');
```

The Problem:

Looking into the image in the console it shows that the image has a title='Nitin' as well as a data-original-title='Click To Open' .

First of all what is this original-title and how is it different then title.

Second I don't want this original-title in the image at all.

how can I acheive it.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you should provide a jsfiddle which replicates your issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's your tooltip plugin that saves the original title of your image into data-original-title to use it later, and maybe restore it, not sure. Removing it dynamically would likely cause problems with the tooltip. Why do you care about this attr being present?

Comment: Yes you are right I have used a Bootstrap tooltip and removing it is removing the data-original-title also.